# how can i extract record count attribute inside the file using Azure data factory?

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, metadata

I have a json file, which has record count in line 3, how can i extract that count using Azure data factory?
getmetadata is not returning the row count when used in copy activity. so cannot use activityoutput.rowcount
the sample input
{
"limit":2,
"offset":0,
"recordcount":1,
"results":[
{
"id":"abc",
"date":"2023-08-09",
"city":"mumbai"
}
]
}

want to extract record count attribute

Answer (score 0):

**You can use lookup activity to look up on file data.**

[image]

**Lookup output:**

[image]

To access **recordcount** from the file use below expression `@string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].recordcount)` or `@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].recordcount`

[image]

**OUTPUT:**

[image]